# Eclipse not recognizing struct declared types

Tags: c, eclipse, struct

I really can't explain this in the title.
I have Eclipse with MingW.
Yesterday I made this

```
typedef struct{
    Offer element;
    OList *next;
}OList;
```

I made a few tests (adding elements, going through a list of elements, simple stuff). Today Eclipse says "unknown type OList". I tried rebuilding the project but it didn't work and it just drives me crazy.
Offer is a type declared in another header and is recognized without problems.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `OList` alias before it has been declared.

Use:

```
typedef struct OList {
    Offer element;
    struct OList *next;
} OList;
```

Comment: Thanks! :) But why? I tried with typedef struct Olist but it wasn't helpful.